# angularjs app appear to be blank after npm install

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

My **app was ok** and could run on localhost:3000. What I did was I removed node_modules folder and do npm install.

Turned out now the app is blank on locahost:3000, no error from the web console and my terminal. I really don't know how to debug in this case.

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Which build tool you are using? gulp or grunt?

Comment: @gulp my gulpfile.js like this http://pastebin.com/tQcm09Qe